# Lectures 'Doing Done' States for each user in course teaching website in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a course website in Ruby on Rails where Courses are main resource and Lectures are nested Resource. Now when user pays for the course then the lectures get open.

I want to have some db or relationship between lectures and users. When users is on show page of lectures then status of that user on the lecture is 'doing' if user moves to next lecture or other lecture then the status should be done.

By this way I want to show users their progress. Please help me how to make models and callings for that

Routes are like this in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
resources :courses, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :lectures, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :enrols, only: [:create]
```

'enrols' enrol user to the courses lectures and authorize them.

app/models/lecture.rb:

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

app/models/course.rb:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lectures, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :coupons, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :enrols, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :enrols
end
```

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrols, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :enrols
end
```

app/models/enrol.rb:

```
class Enrol < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Please let me know if some other code is required to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a many-to-many relation between User and Lecture, that has an attribute named `status`.

```
class UserProgress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lecture
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_progresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lectures, through: :user_progresses
end

class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_progresses, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Changing status when showing lecture:

```
class LecturesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # set all other user's lectures' status to 'done'
    current_user.user_progresses.update_all(status: 'done')

    # set current lecture's status to 'doing'
    progress = current_user.user_progresses.find_or_initialize_by(lecture: @lecture)
    progress.status = 'doing'
    progress.save
    # ...
  end
end
```

And finally, showing all lectures' status on view (haml for example)

```
- current_user.user_progresses.includes(:lecture).each do |progress|
  = progress.lecture.title
  = progress.status
```

Comment: Thanks Hoang for the very nice explanation and solution. One more thing I want to ask is what will be in user_progess table in db?

Comment: It'll hold 2 references to user and lecture, and status attribute